# FB App Invites dialog

Tags: ios, facebook

I am testing out FB "App Invites" feature on iOS with a FB test app and FB test users. I navigate successfully to the native invite dialog, write a description and continue to select users to invite. However when I select the users I want to invite and press send the loading stops and a red explanation mark is shown. Please see the attached image.

Is there way to see what error occured somehow?

[image]

Thanks!!

Comment: What link are you using, and are the proper tags included?

Comment: Hi Ming, I am using an example app https://apps.facebook.com/fb_sample_mtscrumps/ I assume it is properly setup. Do you know about a link which is properly setup that I could test just to see if this works?

Comment: You need to use your own App Links enabled url, or create one using the docs here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-invites/ios which will tell the Facebook app how to open and install your app.